# ERROR: must be owner of language plpgsql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, plpgsql

I'm using `PostgreSQL v9.0.1` with `Rails` (and it's deps) @ `v2.3.8`, owing to the use of the fulltext capability of postgres, I have a table which is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE affiliate_products (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    model character varying(255),
    description text,
    price numeric(9,2),
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    textsearch_vector tsvector,
);
```

Note the last line, this ensures that active record isn't able to process it with the standard schema dumper, so I have to set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `./config/environment.rb`; and use `rake db:test:clone_structure` instead of `rake db:test:clone`.

None of this is too remarkable, only inconvenient - however `rake db:test:clone_structure` fails with the error:

`ERROR:  must be owner of language plpgsql`

Because of line `#16` in my resulting `./db/development_schema.sql`:

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Under `PostgreSQL v9.0+` the language `plpsql` is installed by the superuser, to the initial template, which is then available to the newly created schema.

I cannot run tests on this project without resolving this, and even editing `./db/development_schema.sql` manually is futile as it is regenerated every time I run `rake db:test:clone_structure` (and ignored by `rake db:test:clone`).

I hope someone can shed some light on this?

**Note:** I have used both the `pg 0.9.0` adapter gem, and the `postgres` gem at version `0.7.9.2008.01.28` - both display identical behaviour.

My teammates run `PostgreSQL v8.4` where the language installation is a manual step.

Comment: I've considered that I should drop the `pl/pgsql` language, and install it manually each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was as follows:

On my installation, there are standard templates `template0` and `template1` - at least as I understand it postgres will look for the highest numbered `templateN` when creating a new database, unless the template is specified.

In this instance, as `template0` included `plpgsql`, so did `template1`… the idea being that you will customise `template1` to suite your site specific default needs, and in the case that you blow everything up, you would restore `template1` from `template0`.

As my site specific requirement was to install `plpgsql` as part of the automated build of my web application (a step we had to keep to maintain 8.4 compatibility) - the solution was easy: remove `plpgsql` from `template1` and the warning/error went away.

In the case that the site-specific defaults would change, and we should need to go back to the default behaviour, we would simply remove `template1` and recreate it (which would use `template0`)

Comment: It doesn't take the highest numbered template, it takes `template1` unless you specify something else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Peter, mistake on my part. In the case that you would delete `template1` would `template0` not be the default? (thus supporting my assumption)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. I fixed my template with the commands below

```
psql template1
template1=# alter role my_user_name with superuser;
```

read more at http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2011/07/error-must-be-owner-of-language-plpgsql.html

Comment: This works for me; but what does `alter role my_user_name with superuser;` actually do?

Comment: It makes your my_user_name , SuperUser of postgres.

Comment: This is not a proper solution. I do not want to give this user superuser rights.

Answer (score 21):

For new readers, I read this older post after having run into this error in one of my own projects. I strongly feel that giving the app's PostgreSQL a superuser role is a terrible idea and changing the template is not ideal either.  Since the referenced PSQL commands that are added by `db:structure:dump` are not needed by the Rails app's database, I have written a custom rake task that comments out the problematic lines in structure.sql.  I have shared that code publicly on Github as a Gist at https://gist.github.com/rietta/7898366.

Comment: Your comments are spot on - and the rake file provided in the gist works a peach - Thanks!

Comment: I agree, this should really be the preferred answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for providing up-to-date info, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error while attempting to do `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:reset`. I was able to accomplish the same thing (for my purposes) by doing `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just filter the plpgsql extension statements from the structure.sql file post-dump:

```
# lib/tasks/db.rake

namespace :db do
  desc "Fix 'ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql' complaints from Postgresql"
  task :fix_psql_dump do |task|
    filename = ENV['DB_STRUCTURE'] || File.join(ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.db_dir, "structure.sql")
    sql = File.read(filename)
    sql.sub!(/(CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql)/, '-- \1')
    sql.sub!(/(COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql)/, '-- \1')
    File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(sql)
    end
    task.reenable
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:fix_psql_dump"].invoke
end
```