# How do I add a check constraint in a Rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I need to add a new integer column to an existing table in my Rails app.  The column can only have values 1, 2, 3, so I'd like to add a check constraint to the table/column.  How do I specify this constraint within a Rails migration?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Rails migration does not provide any way to add Constraints, but you can still do it via migration but by passing actual SQL to execute()

Create Migration file:

```
ruby script/generate Migration AddConstraint
```

Now, in the migration file:

```
class AddConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT check_constraint_name CHECK (check_column_name IN (1, 2, 3) )"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT check_constraint_name"
  end
end
```

Comment: Also note that if you do add a constraint, you'll have to set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `config/application.rb` as ["`db/schema.rb` cannot express database specific items such as triggers, stored procedures or check constraints."](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps).

Comment: There's now a gem that supports storing constraints in `db/schema.rb`: [active_record-postgres-constraints](https://github.com/on-site/active_record-postgres-constraints).  See my answer for more details.  For now, only postgres is supported.

Answer (score 43):

#### Rails 6.1+ Check Constraints

[Rails 6.1 added basic support for check constraints to database migrations](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31323).

So now, a migration for adding a check constraint which restricts integer column values only to 1, 2, and 3 can be written as follows:

```rb
class AddConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_check_constraint :table_name, 'check_column_name IN (1, 2, 3)', name: 'check_constraint_name'
  end

  def down
    remove_check_constraint :table_name, name: 'check_constraint_name'
  end
end
```

Here is [a link to the relative PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31323) where you can find more details about [`add_check_constraint`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_check_constraint) and [`remove_check_constraint`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_check_constraint).

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer (or at least be flagged as the modern solution). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with Migration Validators gem. See details here: https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core

With that gem you'll be able to define inclusion validation on db level:

```rb
def change
  change_table :table_name do |t|
    t.integer :column_name, inclusion: [1, 2, 3]
  end
end
```

moreover you is able to define how that validation should be defined and even error message that should be shown:

```rb
def change
  change_table :posts do |t|
    t.integer :priority, 
              inclusion: { in: [1, 2, 3], 
                           as: :trigger, 
                           message: "can't be anything else than 1, 2, or 3" }
  end
end
```

you can even level up that validation from migration right to your model:

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

and then validation defines in migration will be also defined as ActiveModel validation in your model:

```rb
Post.new(priority: 3).valid? 
=> true

Post.new(priority: 4).valid?
=> false

Post.new(priority: 4).errors.full_messages
=> ["Priority can't be anything else than 1, 2, or 3"]
```

Answer (score 5):

### This answer is obsolete as of May 2021

I just published a gem for this: [active_record-postgres-constraints](https://github.com/on-site/active_record-postgres-constraints).  As the [README](https://github.com/on-site/active_record-postgres-constraints#usage) there describes, you can use it with a db/schema.rb file, and it adds support for the following methods in migrations:

```
create_table TABLE_NAME do |t|
  # Add columns
  t.check_constraint conditions
  # conditions can be a String, Array or Hash
end

add_check_constraint TABLE_NAME, conditions
remove_check_constraint TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Note that at this time, only postgres is supported.

Comment: The said gem is not supported anymore because Rails 6.1+ officially provides the option (see Marian13's answer) as [the author too explains](https://github.com/betesh/active_record-postgres-constraints/issues/37#issuecomment-824539916). I observe the gem causes troubles in running `rails app:update`.
Thank you @Isaac Betesh for the gem! It's been useful.

Answer (score 4):

I have just worked through getting a PostgreSQL CHECK constraint to work.

Nilesh's solution is not quite complete; the db/schema.rb file won't include the constraint, so tests and any deployments that use db:setup won't get the constraint.  As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps

> While in a migration you can execute custom SQL statements, the
>   schema dumper cannot reconstitute those statements from the database.
>   If you are using features like this, then you should set the schema
>   format to :sql.

I.e., in config/application.rb set

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Unfortunately, if you're using PostgreSQL you may get an error when loading the resultant dump, see discussion at [ERROR: must be owner of language plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368789/error-must-be-owner-of-language-plpgsql). I didn't want to go down the PostgreSQL configuration path in that discussion; plus in any case i'm fond of having a readable db/schema.rb file.  So that ruled out custom SQL in the migration file for me.

The https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core gem suggested by Valera seems promising, but it only supports a limited set of constraints (and I got an error when I tried to use it, though that may be due to incompatibilities with other gems I'm including).

The solution (hack) I went with is to have the model code insert the constraint.  Since it's kindof like a validation, that's where I put it:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :my_constraint

    def my_constraint
        unless MyModel.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM information_schema.check_constraints WHERE constraint_name = 'my_constraint'").any?
            MyModel.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE my_models ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK ( ...the SQL expression goes here ... )")
        end
    end
```

Of course this does an extra select before each validation; if that's a problem a solution would be to put it in an "after connect" monkey patch such as discussed in [How to run specific script after connected to oracle using rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683209/how-to-run-specific-script-after-connected-to-oracle-using-rails) (You can't simply cache the result of the select, because the validation/constraint addition happens within a transaction that might get rolled back, so you need to check each time.)

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but not scalable. As you say it does an extra select before each validation. If you end up with lots of constraints this will become a performance headache as you scale. I think the post you linked to about firing scripts after initial db connection might be a better way to do this. However, having said that, one could argue that trying to solve the constraints issue should not be done inside Rails, but outside it - Rails is meant to be database agnostic. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589509/does-rails-need-database-level-constraints

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sequel` gem https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table(:artists) do
      primary_key :id
      String :name
      constraint(:name_min_length){char_length(name) > 2}
    end
  end
end
```