# Model attribute data validation at database level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I want to validate that username is not one of the following. `["admin", "moderator", "mod", "administrator"]`.

I do validate that these names are not allowed at the model level using custom validator.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :username_should_not_be

  def username_should_not_be
    not_allowed = ["admin", "moderator", "mod", "administrator"]
    if not_allowed.include?(username.downcase)
      error.add(:username, "is not allowed.")
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I'd like to know if I can validate this at database level as well (maybe using migration file?). Can this be done for the particular case above?

This practise seems to be encouraged by [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#why-use-validations) as well

> it may be a good idea to use some constraints at the database level.
>   Additionally, database-level validations can safely handle some things
>   (such as uniqueness in heavily-used tables) that can be difficult to
>   implement otherwise.

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664520/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-in-a-rails-migration

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: sqlite on dev, postgresql on prod

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with mv-postgresql gem for PostgreSQL and mv-sqlite gem for SQLite. Both gems are the parts of Migration Validator project ( see details here: https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core.

With that gem you can define validation on db level. In your case:

```rb
def up
  validates :users, :username, 
             exclusion: ["admin", "moderator", "mod", "administrator"]
end

def down
   validates :users, :username, exclusion: false
end
```

And then you ( preferably ) propagate that validation to your model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

As result:

```rb
User.new(username: 'admin').valid?
=> false

User.new(username:  'jasoki').valid?
=> true
```