# Raise an error when array does not contain expected data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails (6) app (with PG), I have the `Office` model with `room_ids` which is an array of `UUID`s

```
  t.uuid room_ids, array: true
```

Is there a way to raise some kind of `PG Error`* when an office is created with room_ids containing other than UUIDs?

`Office.create(room_ids: [1])` should raise such Error.

But now

```
Office.create(room_ids: [1])
=> #<Office id: "24e835df-aed9-4d48-8855-82670375c374", room_ids: [nil]>
```

- I'm not looking for Active Record Validations

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing an array of room ids? Why not use an association?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Postgres [*check constraints*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) and the appropriate regex.

Heres a blog post that sums it up nicely: [Rails Validations vs Postgres Check Constraints](https://naildrivin5.com/blog/2015/11/15/rails-validations-vs-postgres-check-constraints.html). From the post:

```
ALTER TABLE 
  users 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
  users_name_must_look_like_a_name 
CHECK (
  name ~* '^.*[a-z] [a-z].*$'
);
```

Although Rails doesn't provide a direct way to add a Postgres check constraint, you can write them manually in a migration, which you can see examples of [in the Rails docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible) or [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664520/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-in-a-rails-migration#answer-4668113):

```rb
class AddConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT check_constraint_name CHECK (check_column_name IN (1, 2, 3) )"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT check_constraint_name"
  end
end
```