# Rails - DB Level Validation for `:start_date` and `:end_date`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, db-schema

I have a question related to the following code in Rails:

```
class CreateEmployments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :employments do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.string :company_name
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to disallow the db to accept any :start_date value greater than :end_date . I want :end_date to be always greater than :start_date and want to do it at the db level. Is there a way to do it?
I know I can use model field validations, but I want to implement it at db level too. Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rules on DB level are called [constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp).

```rb
class AddEmploymentsDateConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE employments ADD CONSTRAINT employments_date_check CHECK (end_date > start_date)"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "ALTER TABLE employments DROP CONSTRAINT employments_date_check"
  end
end
```

It is important to know what DB is used. For instance, if it is used SQLite, can not use `ALTER TABLE` syntax to add constraint - only on `CREATE TABLE` can add constraint. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1884841/16236820).

Additionaly, rails 6.1+ supports constraints, see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63272405/16236820).